# how to convert javaScript array into string And store in Hidden field in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, model-view-controller, hidden-field

onclick Function:-

```
    //$(document).ready(function() {
AddRemoveCustomer = function(){
    var CustomerIDArray =[];
    $(".checkBoxClass").click(function(e) {
        var arr = CustomerIDArray;
        var checkedId =$(this).attr('id');
        if ($(this).prop('checked')){
            CustomerIDArray.push(checkedId);
            arr = CustomerIDArray;
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery.each(CustomerIDArray, function(i, item){
                if (arr[i] == checkedId)
                {
                    arr.splice(i, 1);
                }
            });
            CustomerIDArray = arr;
        }
        var ids = "";
        jQuery.each(CustomerIDArray, function(i, item){
            if (ids == "")
            {
                ids = CustomerIDArray[i];
            }
            else
            {
                ids = ids + "," + CustomerIDArray[i];
            }
        });
        alert(ids);
    });;
    };
    </script>
```

View:-

```
<table id="tblEmailScheduler"  class="table-bordered col-offset-12">
            <thead>
                <tr class="label-primary">
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        First Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        Last Name
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        Email ID
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        Customer Type
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        Customer Designation
                        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerDesignation", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectAllCustomerDesignationDDL, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "CustomerDesignationDDL" , name = "CustomerDesignationDDL" })
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding:5px 15px;">
                        Select All
                        <div class="checkbox control-group">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll" />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        EmailTemplate :
                        @Html.DropDownList("EmailSubject", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectAllEmailTemplateDDL, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "SelectAllEmailTemplateDDL" })
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        Set Date And Time:
                        <input type="text" class = "from-date-picker" readonly = "readonly"  />
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                       <input type="submit" value="Schedule" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </th>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr style="text-align:center">
                    <td id="tblFirstName">
                        @item.FirstName
                    </td>
                    <td id="tblLastName">
                        @item.LastName
                    </td>
                    <td id="tblEmailID">
                        @item.EmailID
                    </td>
                    <td id="tblCustomerType">
                        @item.CustomerType
                    </td>
                    <td id="tblCustomerDesignation">
                        @item.CustomerDesignation
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox control-group">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="@item.CustomerID" value="@item.CustomerID"  onclick="AddRemoveCustomer()" class="checkBoxClass"/>
                                @*@Html.CheckBox("Select", new { id = "cbCustomer", item.CustomerID})*@
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
      </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfCustomerID"/>
```

1. I have given checkbox as i check checkbox value of row stored in array in JavaScript.
2. I want to convert JavaScript array into string and it should save in hidden field.
3. When I click on paging then hidden field value should load in array and then in array it also stores the new checked value with existing value from hidden field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var value=fruits.toString();
```

declare an input in html page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" class="btn btn-default" />
```

using jquery you can set value.

```
 $('#hidden').val(value);
```

Comment: A more cleaner approach is to use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) because `toString()` is a part of Object and can be used on all objects in javascript. If you want to receive arrays only, use the former.